# Ajax call submit array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have the following situation.

In one Javascript (function answer_submit) i call a php file through ajax like so:

```js
$.post("/content/insert_reply.php", {
  id: topicId,
  answerText: answerText,
  linkToShow: linkToShow
}, function(data) {
  call_next_function(data);
});
```

In the called php file i generate an array which will be printed at the end:

```
$previewArrayString = "{url: '".$urlPreview["URL"].
"', pictureUrl: '".$urlPreview["Picture"].
"', title: '".$urlPreview["Title"].
"', description: '".substr($urlPreview["Description"], 0, 160).
"'}";
echo previewArrayString;
```

So the "call_next_function" function is expexting the input to be an array. Whenever i call this function now it tells me, that the input is undefined. 
I tried putting all of the elements i need into a global array in javascript. But when i do that in the called php file the site tells me, that the array is not defined.

So to make a long story short, is there any way for me to create a javascript array in the php and then to retrieve the data through the data part within the js function?

Comment: what you passed to 'insert_reply.php' is json data. take a look at php's json_encode and json_decode

Comment: Your php script does not create an array but an json-object.

Comment: The input of call_next_function() at first will be a String, not an array/object. You need to convert it to JSON first.

Comment: @Blauharley [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Use [`json_encode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create the JSON

Comment: @Andreas: You are right, I meant an object in literal form.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. So how can i decode the data i recieve from the ajax call? Or do i have to do that in the insert_reply.php file?

Comment: to decode the data received from ajax call you can see what you get in the `$_POST` array in php since you are making a post call. if you are sending raw data try using `file_get_contents('php://input'))`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others' suggestion to use json_encode, set the Content-Type header on the php side:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($urlPreview);
```

You can also add an argument to $.post to force the expected response type, but it shouldn't be necessary once you've set the Content-Type.  Anyway, this is how you would do it:

```
$.post("/content/insert_reply.php", {
  id: topicId,
  answerText: answerText,
  linkToShow: linkToShow
}, function(data) {
  call_next_function(data);
}, "json");
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. It still shows that all the contents of the array that i try to use are undefined.

Comment: try examining the returned data in your browser javascript console; perhaps your php code is echoing more than just the json_encode.